# Do I have to retain/release values taken from NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, nsdictionary

Normally I do something like this (below) to get value I need:

```
NSDictionary *state = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"state"];
[self.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:[state objectForKey:@"short"]];
```

But does it worth to do retain/release for values taken from NSDictionary? Something like this:

```
NSDictionary *state = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"state"] retain];
[self.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:[state objectForKey:@"short"]];
[state release];
```

Is it more memory friendly? Or I shouldn't bother and just trust to autorelease pool to do its job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no point in doing that. The result of `[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"state"]` is always an autoreleased object; if you add an extra `retain` and `release`, that won't change anything.

Comment: So it doesn't speed-up release of `state`? Why i think about this -- I saw some posts that told to avoid using `autorelease`ed variables. And release them manually if possible. This is why i think about it...

Comment: @NilColor Yes, sometimes avoiding autoreleased variables can provide speed increases (though usually not much). However my point is that in this situation you can't avoid it, `-objectForKey:` will always return an autoreleased object. So just don't worry about it :)